# Creating and storing images with gtk2?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

I am having some trouble drawing images with gtk2. I have tried this code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean button_press_callback (GtkWidget *event_box, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer data)
{
  g_print ("Event box clicked at coordinates %f,%f\n",
           event->x, event->y);

  /* Returning TRUE means we handled the event, so the signal
   * emission should be stopped (don't call any further
   * callbacks that may be connected). Return FALSE
   * to continue invoking callbacks.
   */
  return TRUE;
}

static GtkWidget*
create_image (void)
{
  GtkWidget *image;
  GtkWidget *event_box;

  image = gtk_image_new_from_file ("image.png");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  create_image();
  return 0;
}
```

It will not draw any images onscreen, infact I don`t see any window at all. Also, what is the best way to store an image in a variable for future use?

Comment: Use GTK+ 2 only if you have to maintain an old code base. GTK+ 3 has been released 8 years ago, and GTK+ 4 is around the corner, most likely released in 2019. Moreover, drawing has changed, the cairo library being a first-class citizen in GTK+ 3.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look at the gtk tutorial https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/, a lot of things are missing for your code to display here a sample on how to display a simple picture in a window :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget* create_gui()
{
    GtkWidget *win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL); // create the application window
    GtkWidget *img = gtk_image_new_from_file("image.png"); // image shall be in the same dir 
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), img); // add the image to the window
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(win), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL); // end the application if user close the window
    return win;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    GtkWidget* win;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);


    win = create_gui();
    gtk_widget_show_all(win); // display the window
    gtk_main(); // start the event loop
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, gtk 2 is no longer being maintained, I suggest you start with gtk3 if you can

Comment: It does not work. I get tons of warnings. Is it ok to have two versions of gtk at once

Comment: On linux with gcc, I don't have any trouble, just be sure of your compile flags. For this example I used gtk2 and the following command line : `gcc \`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0\` -o example example.c \`pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0\` `